# Can't make new Blackberry Project

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde

Basically I use eclipse and I installed the plugin for blackberry, however even know if I go to about and it is listed as installed, I cannot create a new project, or open the perspective either. It's nowhere to be found in the new project menu. I just followed what was on here:

http://us.blackberry.com/developers/javaappdev/javaplugin.jsp

Is there something else I need to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the very same problem.

1. I download blackberry jde 7.1 for eclipse.
2. Try to add new blackberry project, but there are no Blackberry project option.
3. Check my JDK version, turns out I installed jdk 5
4. Remove the jdk 5, and install jdk 6 32 bit, update 31.
5. Reinstall the blackbery jde 7.1.
6. Now I have Blackberry option when i try to add new blackbery project.

Answer (score 1):

Use file -> create new project and inside choose Blackberry Project. Note that you should use the BlackBerry plugin for eclipse to do that

Comment: I go to file and create new project and Blackberry is not listed. I also have installed the Blackberry plugin through eclipse.

Comment: are you running the Blackberry plugin or running eclipse? When you install the blackberry plugin, you will have another icon that represents the blackberry plugin for eclipse

Comment: I'm running eclipse and have installed the plugin via the install software ability.

Comment: Download the eclipse plugin from the blackberry website and run it ... This is what I did and worked

Comment: It should be noted that the BlackBerry JDK also doesn't support the latest Eclipse versions. The latest JDK for example, bundles Eclipse Helios with it.

Answer (score 1):

Download the Eclipse and Blackberry installation bundle and you're good to go. It combines the two and avoids having to install new software.

Answer (score 0):

i had this issue and the steps on blackberrys site helped me to resolve it:

from:  [BlackBerry Developer Site](https://developer.blackberry.com/java/download/eclipse/)

In your existing Eclipse environment, follow the steps below:

From the Help menu, select Install New Software to open the Install window.
Click Add:
In the Add Site dialog, type the URL http://www.blackberry.com/developers/jar/win/java into the location text box and specify BlackBerry Java Plug-in Update Site in the name text box.
Click OK, BlackBerry Update Site appears in the Available Software list.
Select the BlackBerry Java Plug-in item and at least one BlackBerry SDK you want to work with. Choose the version of the BlackBerry SDK which ensures that your application is compatible with your intended target market. Read more about SDK versions.
Click Next.
Click Next after reviewing the items to be installed.
Check I accept the terms of the license agreement after reviewing the licenses.
Click Finish to begin installation.
After successfully downloading the files, you'll be prompted to restart Eclipse.